# Perl Package Method is Returning Package Name as First Parameter

Tags: perl

I have two nested packages that I am calling via fast_cgi.  From the first Package I am invoking a method from the second like so:

```
$MyScalar = "A Value";
MyPackage::Inner->InvokeMe($MyScalar);
```

From my other package, I'm unwinding the parameters like this:

```
sub ZonesByCustomer($)
{
    my $MyParameter = @_[0];
    print $MyParameter;
}
```

What I'd expect is to have `A Value` get printed out, however what is actually getting printed out is `MyPackage::Inner`.  `A Value` is actually being stored in `@_[1]`.

This seems confusing.  Why is the package name getting returned as a parameter?

This is abstracted from my code.  I can provide a slightly more complicated version if I am missing something here that is essential.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perl doesn't have a "this" variable (implied or otherwise) like many other languages, yet the method needs that information. Instead, Perl provides the class (static method call) or object (instance method call) as the first argument of the method. The result of evaluating the argument list follows.

Example of static method requiring class name:

```
sub new {
   my ($class, %args) = @_;
   return bless(\%args, $class);
}

SomeClass->new(...);
```

Example of instance method requiring object:

```
sub as_string {
   my ($self) = @_;
   return $self->{val};
}

$some_object->as_string();
```

---

Note: `@_[0]` and `@_[1]` should be `$_[0]` and `$_[1]`.

Note: Prototypes are generally bad, and ignored during method calls. Get rid of it.

Comment: I should have said "yet the method needs *this* information" haha :D

Comment: @ikegami Prototypes are the ($) part of the subroutine declaration? Why are prototypes bad? I switched the reading of the variables from a my ($argument) = @_ for the sake of clarity--my bad.

Answer (score 3):

This is from [`perlootut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html#Methods).

> When we make a method call, Perl arranges for the method's invocant to
>   be passed as the first argument. Invocant is a fancy name for the
>   thing on the left side of the arrow. The invocant can either be a
>   class name or an object.

So Perl is doing what it is supposed to for a method call.

```
MyPackage::Inner->InvokeMe($MyScalar)
```

is identical to

```
MyPackage::Inner::InvokeMe('MyPackage::Inner', $MyScalar)
```

If you look at the contents of the parameter array `@_` you will see that `$_[1]` is the value of `$MyScalar`.

(Incidentally your syntax for accessing the first parameter is wrong. You should write `$_[0]` as one element of an array is a *scalar*.)

Comment: It's actually close to `MyPackage::Inner->can('InvokeMe')->('MyPackage::Inner', $MyScalar)`.

Answer (score 1):

That is how OO works in Perl. Package methods take the package name as their first argument, object methods take the object as their first argument. Therefore, you can define the constructor as a package method:

```
sub new {
    my ($class) = @_;
    bless {}, $class;
}
```

and you can operate on the object itself inside a method:

```
sub frobnicate {
    my ($self) = @_;
    $self->_do_frob if $self->_is_frobnicable;   
}
```

Comment: <pedant>frobnicatable</pedant>